# Borders and background of QWidget aren't set by stylesheet

Tags: qt, background, border, stylesheet, qwidget

I've set the stylesheet of a `QWidget` to change the borders and the background,

```
#gui {
    border: 4px inset #515c84;
    border-radius: 9px;
    background-image: url(./back.png)
}
```

Its name is `gui` but neither border nor background are shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PySide: QWidget does not draw background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104051/pyside-qwidget-does-not-draw-background-color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `paintEvent` in your `QWidget` subclass like this:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QStylePainter p(this);
    p.drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, opt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Python-QT bindings (PyQt, PySide) just setting the attribute `WA_StyledBackground` on the QWidget is enough to show border and background.

Comment: @user1153551 I think it does provide an answer. Does it not work?

Comment: @user1153551 Okay, I limited my answer to the python qt bindings. Would be interested to know if the same fails on C++.