# Pyside Qt centralwidget set stylesheet not working

Tags: python, css, pyqt, pyside

I have a Qt Designer built GUI I am building with the PySide framework and the css file works fine in the designer tool but after I have used the `pyside-uic` tool the css on the centralwidget object stops working.

I am using the pyside-uic tool as follows:

```
pyside-uic.exe FileIn.ui -o FileOut.py
```

In the generated code i have:

```
self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
```

For the CSS i have:

```
MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QWidget#centralwidget{background-color: 
qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.683, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0
rgba(103, 103, 103,255), stop:1 rgba(144, 144, 144, 255));
"}
```

The first line shows a warning in PyCharm stating:

**"Instance attribute centralwidget defined outside __init__"**

In the CSS if I target the QWidget i can get the style i want on the central widget but it then over rides the rest of my GUI.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like an error on your behalf. Can you please edit your question to include **How you are using the pyside-uic tool** and **how you are implementing the styles to your widgets?** The code you have shown in your question does not include any widget related styles (CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your issue is that bare `QWidget` has no background. You can either implement it as an own widget with custom `paintEvent()` or just use `QFrame`.

The following code works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        widget = QtGui.QFrame()
        widget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.resize(480,320)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("#centralwidget { background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.683, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(103, 103, 103,255), stop:1 rgba(144, 144, 144, 255)); }")

    window = MainWindow()    
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for that but sadly no difference

Comment: Thanks for that i have just seen your comment but i have managed to get it working another way but i like the look of your way better so i will try and implement this in my code and see how i get on

Comment: I guess [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104051/pyside-qwidget-does-not-draw-background-color) is the best possible solution.

Comment: Yes that is definitely the easiest way too. I appreciate your help