# Why is QWidget with border and background image styling behaving different to QLabel, QDialog, ...?

Tags: qt, background, stylesheet, pyside, qwidget

I use the Qt4.8 Python binding PySide (version 1.2.2 on Python 3.3 on Windows) and I see that `QWidget` behaves different from `QWidget`derived widgets like `QDialog`, `QLabel` or `QMainWindow` when styling with stylesheets.

In particular I observe that the attribute `WA_StyledBackground` must be set to show a border or a background image while a background color is set independently. In contrast for the other widgets this attribute has no influence, a border or background image is always shown. Overriding the `paintEvent` method is also a possibility.

Example code:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        opt = QtGui.QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        painter.drawPrimitive(QtGui.QStyle.PE_Widget, opt)

def display(w):
    print(w.__class__.__name__)
    w.setWindowTitle(w.__class__.__name__)
    print(' WA_StyledBackground is {}'.format(w.testAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)))
    print(' autoFillBackground is {}'.format(w.autoFillBackground()))
    w.setStyleSheet('border: 4px inset #515c84; border-radius: 9px; background-color: blue; background-image: url(test.png);')
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

w1 = QtGui.QMainWindow(flags=QtCore.Qt.Window)
display(w1) # works

w2 = QtGui.QDialog(f=QtCore.Qt.Window)
display(w2) # works

w3 = QtGui.QWidget(f=QtCore.Qt.Window)
w3.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)
display(w3) # works only with the previous line uncommented

w4 = QtGui.QLabel('Text', f=QtCore.Qt.Window)
display(w4) # works

w5 = MyWidget(f=QtCore.Qt.Window)
display(w5) # works

app.exec_()
```

This topic is already discussed partly on StackOverflow. The accepted answer on [Borders and background of QWidget aren't set by stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257177/borders-and-background-of-qwidget-arent-set-by-stylesheet) suggests overriding `paintEvent`, the accepted answer of [How to set QWidget background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655538/how-to-set-qwidget-background-color) suggests to set `setAutoFillBackground` in case one uses the palette and [PySide: QWidget does not draw background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104051/pyside-qwidget-does-not-draw-background-color) suggests to just set the above mentioned `WA_StyledBackground`. What is missing is the reason for the differences between `QWidget` and derived widgets.

I find these differences a bit confusing:

- Why is `QWidget` behaving different from derived widgets like `QLabel`,...?
- Why can `QWidget` in the natural state not display borders or background images but it does diplay background colors?
- Is there a difference between setting attribute `WA_StyledBackground` and overridding `paintEvent` in the described way? Which method would be preferred?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr - Use `QFrame`

I won't attempt to guess at the reasoning that went into this design decision, but generally speaking `QWidget` is considered to be borderless. If you want your widget to have nice styled borders, then you should probably be using a `QFrame`, which essentially just a `QWidget` with the border styling capabilities that you're looking for.

You'll note that a lot of widgets (such as the `QLabel` you've mentioned) actually inherit from `QFrame` rather than directly from `QWidget`.

I can't speak authoritatively in regards to the `WA_StyledBackground` property.

Comment: I don't really need the QFrame because I don't need the special frames offered there, working stylesheets are enough. I guess I'm just searching for the minimal widget that supports stylesheets properly. QFrame may be a possibility.

Comment: If you want to use style sheets to style the border, you need to use QFrame

Comment: As soon as I set a style sheet on a QFrame including a border directive any custom border of QFrame is dismissed and there is no difference to a QWidget in behavior. I think QFrame is useless unless one wants one the special borders from it.